# How to find all patterns between two characters?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, regex

I'm trying to find all patterns between a pair of double quotes. Let say I have a file with contents look like as following:

```
first matched is "One". the second is here"Two "
and here are in second line" Three ""Four".
```

I want to below words as output:

```
One
Two
Three
Four
```

As you can see all strings in output are between a pair of quotes.

What I tried, is this command:

```
grep -Po ' "\K[^"]*' file
```

Above command works fine if I have a space before first pair of `"` marks. For example it works if my input file contains the following:

```
first matched is "One". the second is here "Two "
and here are in second line " Three " "Four".
```

I know I can do this with multiple commands combination. But I'm looking for one command and without using that for multiple time. e.g: below command

```
grep -oP '"[^"]*"' file | grep -oP '[^"]*'
```

How can I achieve/print all of my patterns just using one command?

Reply to comments: It's not important for me to removing whitespace around matched pattern inside a pair of quotes, but it would be better if the command support it too. and also my files contain nested quotes like `"foo "bar" zoo"`. And all of the quoted words are in separate lines and they are not expanded to multi lines.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you have nested quotes? Things like `"foo "bar""`? If yes, how should those be dealt with?

Comment: @terdon I wrote I think `"One". the second is here "Two "` and also `" Three ""Four"` are nested. isn't it?

Comment: No, nested would be where the first quote includes the second. Yours are just next to each other. Nested: `"foo "bar" baz"`, not nested:` "foo""bar"`.

Comment: Is it possible for the quoted text to contain newlines?

Comment: Also, why do you want `Three` and not ' Three ' as an answer? Should whitespace be removed?

Comment: I meant why 'Three' with no spaces instead of ' Three ' with spaces which is what you actually have. Do you need whitespace to be removed from the matched patterns. Also, please [edit] your question and include these details we're asking, they are needed for the answers.

Comment: @KasiyA could you post a single example which satisfies all your needs along with the expected output?

Comment: @KasiyA added an answer, check it :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, your `grep -Po '"\K[^"]*' file` idea fails because `grep` sees both `"One"` and `". the second is here"` as being inside quotes. Personally, I'd probably just do

```
$ grep -oP '"[^"]+"' file | tr -d '"'
One
Two 
 Three 
Four
```

But that is two commands. To do it with a single command, you could use one of:

1. Perl

   ```
   $ perl -lne '@F=/"\s*([^"]+)\s*"/g; print for @F' file 
   One
   Two 
   Three 
   Four
   ```

   Here, the `@F` array holds all matches of the regex (a quote, followed by as many non-`"` as possible until the next `"`). The `print for @F` just means "print each element of `@F`.
2. Perl

   ```
   $ perl -F'"' -lne 'for($i=1;$i<=$#F;$i+=2){print $F[$i]}' file 
   One
   Two 
    Three 
   Four
   ```

   To remove leading/trailing spaces from each match, use this:

   ```
   perl -F'"' -lne 'for($i=1;$i<=$#F;$i+=2){$F[$i]=~s/^\s*|\s$//; print $F[$i]}' file
   ```

   Here, Perl is behaving like `awk`. The `-a` switch causes it to automatically split input lines into fields on the character given by `-F`. Since I have given it `"`, the fields are:

   ```
   $ perl -F'"' -lne 'for($i=0;$i<=$#F;$i++){print "Field $i: $F[$i]"}' file 
   Field 0: first matched is 
   Field 1: One
   Field 2: . the second is here
   Field 3: Two 
   Field 0: and here are in second line
   Field 1:  Three 
   Field 2: 
   Field 3: Four
   Field 4: .
   ```

   Because we are looking for text between two consecutive field separators, we know we want every second field. So, `for($i=1;$i<=$#F;$i+=2){print $F[$i]}` will print the ones we care about.
3. The same idea but in `awk`:

   ```
   $ awk -F'"' '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=2){print $(i)}}' file 
   One
   Two 
    Three 
   Four
   ```

Comment: Is there any option to remove last printed char like `\b` for example in c++.

Comment: @KasiyA where? What printed char? From which of the suggestions?

Comment: @KasiyA to do it without scripting, just use the `grep`/`tr` suggestion. Remember that pipes are The UNIX Way®, there's no reason to avoid them. You can't do it in `grep` (at least I don't think so) because `grep` will start matching again where the last match ended, which means that after the first hit, everything will start with a `"`.

Answer (score 2):

The key is to consume the quotes in your expression. Hard to do that with a single grep command. Here's a perl one-liner:

```
perl -0777 -nE 'say for /"(.*?)"/sg' file
```

That slurps the whole input and prints out the captured part of the match. It will work even if there's a newline inside the quotes, although it then becomes difficult to separate elements with and without newlines. To help with that, use a different character as the output record separator, the null character for instance

```
perl -0777 -lne 'print for /"(.*?)"/sg} BEGIN {$\="\0"' <<DATA | od -c
blah "first" blah "second
quote with newline" blah "third"
DATA
```

```
0000000   f   i   r   s   t  \0   s   e   c   o   n   d  \n   q   u   o
0000020   t   e       w   i   t   h       n   e   w   l   i   n   e  \0
0000040   t   h   i   r   d  \0
0000046
```

Comment: Thank you Glenn my this command `grep -Po ' "\K[^"]*' file` works if I have a single space before first left pair of `"`s in my input file. Is there any replace regex that I change space here `... -Po '[HERE]"\K ...`  with that regex. replacing space char to match for all chars like `[a-zA-Z]`

Comment: @KasiyA no. The problem is that `grep` will match the `One` and print it. Then, the remaining text is `". the second is here"` which also matches. I don't think that grep's PCRE engine has any way of avoiding that.

Comment: which is why I wrote that the expression must **consume** the trailing quote.

Comment: @glennjackman exactly. Do you have any idea if that's possible in `grep`?

Answer (score 1):

This could be possible with the below grep one liner and i assumed that you have balanced quotation marks.

```
grep -oP '"\s*\K[^"]+?(?=\s*"(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)' file
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat file
first matched is "One". the second is here"Two "
and here are in second line" Three ""Four".
$ grep -oP '"\s*\K[^"]+?(?=\s*"(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)' file
One
Two
Three
Four
```

Another hair pulling solution through PCRE verb [(`*SKIP)(*F)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26272200/3297613),

```
$ grep -oP '[^"]+(?=(?:"[^"]*"[^"]*)*[^"]*$)(*SKIP)(*F)|\s*\K[^"]+(?=\b\s*)' file
One
Two
Three
Four
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`:

```bsh
sed 's/[^"]*"\([^"]\+\)"[^"]*/\1\n/g' file
```

---

```bsh
[^"]*
```

The `^` at the beginning of `[^"]* ...` means that the characters listed in the character class should not match(only match single `"`). The `*` means `"` can occur zero or more times.

```bsh
"\([^"]\+\)"
```

Everything inside `\(...\)` is a matching group. The first character outside of the matching group is the start match. A character class `[^"]` is following(It matches every character except of the `"`). The quantifier `\+` means there must be at least one character between the quotes(`"..."`) in your input file. Then `\)`, the end of the matching group. This matching group can be access by its index via `\1`.

The last part `[^"]*` is the same as the first part that matches everything until the next `"`.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach with Python that doesn't require regular expressions (although not exactly robust), is to process each line in your textfile character by character.

Basic idea of how this works: if we see double quote and no flag raised - raise the flag, and if we see it again and flag is raised - lower the flag. When the flag is raised - that's how we know we're within double quotes, so we can store the subsequent characters. Once the flag is lowered, print what we have read.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
import sys

flag=False
quoted_string=[]
for line in sys.stdin:
    for char in line.strip():
        if char == '"':
           if flag:
               flag=False
               if quoted_string:
                  print("".join(quoted_string))
                  quoted_string=[]
           else:
               flag=True
               continue 
        if flag:
           quoted_string.append(char)
```

And test run:

```
$ cat input.txt
first matched is "One". the second is here"Two "
and here are in second line" Three ""Four".

$ ./get_quoted_words.py < input.txt                                                                                      
One
Two 
 Three 
Four
```